# What's the best way to programatically have a MySQL DB update another MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, cron

I am currently working for a service provider that offers Windows software for inventory control. This software connects to a MySQL DB on a dedicated server.

So when this software is updated it sends the update to the DB. What I'd like to have happen, is when this update is made in the main DB it somehow updates another MySQL DB, which happens to be WordPress.

I just don't know what the "somehow" is right now. Not sure if that's a cron job or something else where the main DB is constantly monitored.

Any and all help is appreciated

Comment: You can start from read many similar question there, for example - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165040/performance-impact-mysql-replication-vs-table-synchronisation-script/165093#165093

Comment: See `FEDERATEDX`.